# rails model action check

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have **Coupon model** and in this model file I have a **suitable_for_use** method.I want to list Coupons **if coupon.suitable_for_use == true**.Is there any short way to do this ? I wrote this code but it doesn't work.

```
@coupons = []
coupons = Coupon.all.each do |coupon|
  if coupon.suitable_for_use
    @coupons << coupon
  end
end
@coupons = coupons
```

**suitable_for_use method**

```
def suitable_for_use
    result = true
    if is_used?
      result = false
    elsif self.start > Time.now.in_time_zone 
      result = false
    elsif self.end < Time.now.in_time_zone
      result = false
    end
    return result
  end
```

Comment: Can you paste the code for `suitable_for_use`?

Comment: And what is the code for is_used?. I'm asking because the best option here is a an AR scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your assigning twice to @coupons. The return value from `each` is the collection it was given. So your last line reassigns the original set of coupons returned by `Coupon.all`.

```
@coupons = Coupon.all.select(&:suitable_for_use)
```

If your not sure what that does, here's the expanded version.

```
@coupons = Coupon.all.select {|coupon| coupon.suitable_for_select}
```

Basically, select takes a block that it will iterate over and if the block returns true then it will add that element to the returned collection. So any coupon that returns false will not be returned by select.

The &:suitable_for_use is called a symbol to proc. It literally expands to the block in the second line and is pretty common in ruby one-liners.

Comment: is `start` nil for one of your coupons? The only place your calling that is in your 2nd check in suitable.

Comment: I solve the problem adding line "elsif self.start.nil? || self.end.nil? result = false" in suitable_for_use checkings.Thank you Cluster

Comment: Generally it is a good idea to add validations to columns like that so that they cannot be nil, unless of course you want them to be nil, then your check is correct.

Comment: I got it.Cluster is there any way to shorten this code.I'm asking here because its related to this issue.if !params[:project][:coupon_id].blank?
        coupon = DiscountCoupon.find(params[:project][:coupon_id])
        coupon.use(@project)
      end

Comment: probably, ruby is pretty flexible, but I would stick with what you have, it makes it clear whats going on. Shorter may look neater, but it can often make your code more unreadable and thus less maintainable.